# Best approach to create custom object records in Apex within managed package?

Tags: apex, managed-package, standard-objects

**Background**: We would like our managed package to create standard object records (Leads, Cases, Contacts) on behalf of the user, in Apex.  Outside of dealing with the *built-in* required fields (e.g. LastName, Company for Leads), the code of course also has to contend with any custom required fields, unique fields, and validation rules that the customer may have installed on these objects.

**Question**: Should we (a) use techniques such as those discussed [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/AppExchange-Directory-Packaging/Standard-Objects-and-managed-package/td-p/429493) and addressed in a github project [here](https://github.com/mbotos/SmartFactory-for-Force.com) to handle required and unique fields?  But then how to deal with validation rules that might cause inserts to fail? or (b) abandon the whole idea of creating records on behalf of the user without their input? or (c) ask the Admin to provide a list of field names and default values that the Apex code can use to create a proper, valid record of each type.

I'm thinking the only viable/user-friendly option is (b), but I'm really curious to hear from other ISV folks who have dealt with this problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many factors that can impact your ability as an ISV to create records via Apex that the support time you end up needing to deal with the errors probably outweighs the benefits.

If it is something you really need to offer, I would probably go down the route of using having a custom setting in your app that you populate on install of the package that would provide a field map of fields for each object you want to create dynamically and a default value for each field, so the admin in the target org can modify those to match their validation rules/workflows etc...and you would probably also need a custom setting to store defaults for each record e.g. default record types if they have them enabled, default accounts for Contacts etc...

Comment: "Custom setting with field map", brr... Wonder if you could specify in managed package a handful of fieldsets with "name you expect" and client org admins could modify their content / requiredness of the fields. Defaults I'd leave as is, that's their whole point, right?

Comment: Thanks to you both for your thoughts.  I appreciate the feedback.  We have decided to use a design that avoids the issue altogether and forces the user to create these records and provide appropriate values manually.  Cheers!